# Rails 4.1 on Windows 8.1 - Suddenly all form post to wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

At first I have been wondering why my app suddenly (2 days ago) get `Routing Error` whenever I submit **new** or **edit** form.

Then I re-install the Ruby on my Windows 8.1 and still got the same error.

Lastly, I create fresh new Rails app with just scaffold:

```
rails new fortest
rails g scaffold products name:string price:decimal

rake db:migrate
bundle install

rails s
```

And I got the exact same error. So the problem isn't my app or 3rd-party gem (since it also happened on new fresh app).

Is there possibility that external software affecting this? The only software updated or installed before I got this error are ESET Antivirus and Steam game.

Thanks

**[EDIT 1]**

Here's the error message

When I create **new** entry:

```
No route matches [POST] "/products/new"
```

When **editting** the entry:

```
No route matches [PATCHES] "/products/1/edit"
```

The weird part is if I press BACK and re-submit the form, it submits just fine.

If I go to another page and return to the **Create New** page, it will get error on first submit and success on second try onward.

**[EDIT 2]**

I can confirm that this issue only happen on Chrome Developer version. IE11 and Firefox works fine.

I will test whether it's plugin issue or bug in Chrome.

Comment: Do you have IIS running on Windows? I've had problems in the past when IIS was running alongside other server services.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to check ISS running, but I have checked my `Task Manager` and didn't found any process that named like `ISS`.

Comment: Have a look at your services. IIS is Internet Information Services (Microsofts web server)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services you should see it as a running service.

Comment: Hi, I don't see that service running. It looks like that is for .NET Development? For a side note, I haven't do .NET Development in my machine.

Comment: Okay. Then that won't be the issue. Yes, it's used for ASP.NET and the like. I thought it might have been configured by default.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll try system restore maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue only occur on Chrome 37 Beta.

I revert back to Chrome 36 Release, and everything works fine.

I guess that's the risk of using Beta version.

Comment: It's not Windows specific; I had the same on OS X; updating Chrome did the trick